# viewmodel two way data binding with list type data Kotlin in android

Tags: android, viewmodel, 2-way-object-databinding

have this code, in viewModel (kotlin)

```
    private val _shoeData = MutableLiveData<List<Shoe>>()
val shoeData : LiveData<List<Shoe>>
    get() {
        return _shoeData
    }
```

how two-data-binding can be implemented in a View (e.g: Fragment), like below wouldn't work

```
android:text="@={shoeStoreViewModel.shoeData.name}"
```

as shoeData is now a list

Comment: if you want to use a list you can use RecyclerView to show separate items, otherwise you need to remove the list and show single Shoe

Comment: how the above statement in .xml file would work, or it would stay same as it is being used in 'two - way' binding to get the data (as output) and not enter or 'display'

Comment: what exaactly do you want to do? Do you want to show the List of shoes or the name of a particular shoe?

Comment: (assuming a list), but above xml code is the one that is providing / feeding (supposed to be observed) the viewModel, that would in go to another .xml for display in a List (e.g: using a recyclerView)

Comment: ... the above mentioned attribute is from <EdiText> element that is being used by user to provide data (name, for example) that is being observed